# GAS　添付メール自動保存時の容量オーバーエラー

Tags: google-apps-script

エラー
Exception: File レポート exceeds the maximum file size.

ファイルサイズが50MB以上になると上記エラーになります（50MBは問題なく指定のドライブへ保存できます）
上限を上げる方法、解消方法等ございますでしょうか。
ご確認お願いいたします。